# How can I give my right div margin top property here?

Tags: css

Hi,

I want the right div with red background some margin top property but still stay the same in the blue box. How can I achieve this? If I give margin top to the div now, it moves the whole blue div.

```html
<div id="wrapper" style="width: 100%;height: 100px; background-color: blue">
  <div id="left" style="background-color: green; height: 50px; width: 50px;  display: inline-block; float: left">
    left
  </div>
  <div id="right" style="background-color: red; height: 50px; width: 50px; margin-left: 50px;">
    right
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Add `float: left;` and remove `margin-left` in red div

```html
<div id="wrapper" style="width: 100%;height: 100px; background-color: blue">
  <div id="left" style="background-color: green; height: 50px; width: 50px;  display: inline-block; float: left">
    left
  </div>
  <div id="right" style="background-color: red; height: 50px; width: 50px; float: left; margin-top: 10px;">
    right
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But I want the red div to stay at the same place horizontally. I do not want the red div to move to the other side of the blue box.

Comment: I update my answer.. can you add screen shot of this?

Comment: Just use float:left instead then.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `float` on both elements (if at all. A nice alternative to using `float` is using `flexbox`). You also don't need the `margin-left`.

```css
#right {
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  float: left
}

#left {
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  float: left
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="left">
    left
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    right
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using

```css
#left {
  background-color: green; height: 50px; width: 50px; float: left;
}
#right {
  background-color: red; height: 50px; width: 50px; margin-top:20px; float:left; margin-left:20px;
}
#wrapper {
width: 100%;height: 100px; background-color: blue; display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="left">
    left
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    right
  </div>
</div>
```